How to get all tokens in my account with python?
I am using solana, python. I have tried to get all tokens in my own account with get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed (program_id=TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA) in python. the result include pump tokens such as Dfh5DzRgSvvCFDoYc2ciTkMrbDfRKybA4SoFbPmApump, but I can't get HeLp6NuQkmYB4pYWo2zYs22mESHXPQYzXbB8n4V98jwC. anyone help?
